# Language identification

Tags: thai, language-identification, khmer

Does this appear to be Thai to you?  The script is on a piece of pottery a friend of mine found in the U.S.
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not Thai. I'm almost sure the script is [Javanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javanese_script), but it's upside-down in your picture. The language is not necessarily Javanese, because the script is used for several languages; check out the link for more info.